# Why does my 1st Gen Apple TV say my TV Shows are not authorized?

Tags: jailbreak, appletv, authorization

I'm trying to play two HD TV Shows on my jailbroken 1st Gen Apple TV. When I try to play them, I get the 'authorizing' message and then I see

'Your Apple TV is not authorized to play this content.'

An SD show works fine and music plays fine. Deauthorizing/Reauthorizing both the mac (itunes source) and ATV has no effect.

Comment: Can we presume the same shows play properly when you use the non-jail broken OS on the device?

Comment: When I first hooked it up (factory default), they played. They did not play after the jailbreak. However, they still don't play after reverting to the factory default.

Comment: Wow - if after a wipe and restore, lemme think what could be up. Are date and time correct? It's been a while since I've used the old device so I'll have to dig in the KB for other troubleshooting steps.

Comment: FWIW, Last night I updated the firmware from 2.2 to 3.0.2 (i think that's right) and then they played. Restored to factory (2.2) and again they did not play. I really want to stay on the older firmware.

Comment: On [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1453) can you play trailers and does the content on question play on your iTunes? It might need a sign our / sign in on your computer to get a new cert from the iTunes store o. Your computer...

Comment: I signed-in/out multiple times on both the unit itself and the mac. I did not try movie trailers, because menu items like that one are the reason I jailbroke the unit in the first place. I just want menu items for the content I've purchased and loaded myself, nothing else. The unit can get to the internet because I was able to download the firmware update.